# Microdisplacement Bug?

Tags: texturing

I am using blender 2.79 and I think I might be experiencing a bug.

I have been using microdisplacements for a few months and I've had solid results, until a few days ago. My set up is normal, I've set blender to experimental, and I'm using 'true', as opposed to bump. My renders recently have had a weird rigid effect where it distinguishes faces, almost as if the mesh has been set to flat.

I have tried uninstalling blender and reinstalling, using different computers, and even following along with tutorials just in case I've possibly forgotten a step, yet the problem still persists and im following the tutorials correctly.

[image]

Comment: additionally, this problem also persists even when i am close up to the mesh. i forgot to mention that adaptive subdivision surface is on!

Comment: Could you upload your Blend-file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? I'll have a look then.

And you could try this: In the Texture-Node change the first drop-down from color to non-color data.

Comment: That seems to be visible and dependant on Dicing Scale in Subsurf modifier settings, if decreasing it (and increasing amount of geometry) then problem becomes less visible

Comment: is you mesh set to smooth shading?

Comment: set your displacement texture to "non color data" also run it through a math node set to multiply. I find this help.

Comment: It’s your file depth. 16 bit tiff as opposed 8 bit jpg

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this a couple of times and it turned out to be one of the following:

the mesh is insufficiently subdivided (or not subdivided at all) before microdisplacement is executed

the mesh is overly subdivided before microdisplacment is executed

the max subdivisions setting is too low for the distance from camera to mesh (properties > render (set to experimental feature set) > geometry > max subdivisions)

the solution that worked for me in all cases was to find the sweet spot between too much and too little subdivision before I applied microdisplacement - in some situations (for reasons of available RAM) I was never able to get the visible mesh resolution to disappear entirely but it became a non-issue when motion blur was applied and/or when the render was viewed full frame (as opposed to very close in a pixel-peeping zoom-in)